# How to use a postgres base from an older version?

Tags: postgresql

I've been sent a data folder for a postgres v8.4 server.
I only have a v11 server and it does not let me start the base, printing that the database files are incompatible with the server because it had been initialized with PGSQL v8.4.
Is there a way for me to upgrade the base so the v11 server can use it?

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin>pg_ctl start pg_ctl : un autre
>   serveur semble en cours d'exécution ; le démarrage du serveur va
>   toutefois être tenté en attente du démarrage du serveur....2019-01-07
>   10:08:11.269 GMT [25476] LOG:  ignore le fichier de configuration «
>   C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data/postgresql.auto.conf » manquant
>   2019-01-07 10:08:11 GMT FATAL:  les fichiers de la base de données
>   sont incompatibles avec le serveur 2019-01-07 10:08:11 GMT DÉTAIL:  Le
>   répertoire des données a été initialisé avec PostgreSQL version 8.4,
>           qui est non compatible avec cette version 11.1.  attente arrêtée pg_ctl : n'a pas pu démarrer le serveur Examinez le journal
>   applicatif.
>
> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin>

Comment: Tu trouveras certainement plus d'informations ici : https://forums.postgresql.fr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade the database to a format that is compatible with version 11.

Your options are either to dump the database using the supplied program
`pg_dumpall` and construct a new database,
or to upgrade it using `pg_upgrade`.

You will find more information in the following PostgreSQL documentation:

- [Upgrading a PostgreSQL Cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/upgrading.html)
- [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgupgrade.html)

I would advice, if you opt for the upgrade in-place of `pg_upgrade`,
to copy the data elsewhere for this operation.

Comment: So regardless of the upgrade method I use, I'll need an installation of PGSQL in the older version to make it work. As is, I'm better off requesting a dump from my source.